# I can't understand his typedef with pointer usage, can someone explain?

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

I had a school project a time ago and at the time I was studying C, but now that it's been a  while a can't understand pointers with such ease. The code is as follows:

```
    typedef struct {
     Identification id;
     Ring edge;
     Ring *holes;
     in nHoles;
    } Parcel;

    typedef Parcel *Cartography;
    //this is the definition of Cartography
    
    
    
    *cartography = malloc(sizeof(Parcel));
    
    *(*cartography + idx) = readParcel(f);
    //this is the code when I want to insert a new Parcel into Cartography
```

I don't understand why do I have to use " * " 2 times when I'm trying to add a new Parcel, can someone explain it to me?

Is it beacause the value in cartography is the address of the malloc and so the first * gives me the that address and the second * takes me to that address?

Thank you all very much for the help!!

Comment: what is the `Parcel`.

Comment: `*(*cartography + idx)` looks wrong. At first look, it should be `*(cartography + idx)` or, equivalently, `cartography[idx]`

Comment: @pmg if Parcel is a pointer as well. so not necessarily - but question without showing what the Parcel is unanswerable

Comment: It it was written by your teacher or used as an example program - it is horrible. One of the worst C practices - hiding the pointers in the typedefs.

Comment: "I can't understand his typedef with pointer", yes, no surprise. You confirm @P__J__ recommendation not to use typedefs which hide pointers.

Comment: @P__J__ that *is* the received wisdom, yes, but when I was first using pointers, it **was** easier to write compilable code with a pointer `typedef`, and that got me started. It wasn't a matter of hiding, but facilitating. When I became happier with pointers, I dispensed with that. Let's not underestimate the struggle that beginners have with pointers in C.

Comment: this was something my teacher wrote with the idea that it would help us with pointers since in my opinion it is super hard when learning C

Comment: @pmg yes that's what I thought, but I remember that when I was doing this project that that wouldn't work, I think it has something to do with the way we do the malloc

Comment: @pIO You have both `Cartography` and `cartography`, with different capitalizations. Those are not the same, since C is case sensitive. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the posted code is a little confusing...

You made a new type Parcel for a structure with 'typedef'.

```
    typedef struct {
     Identification id;
     Ring edge;
     Ring *holes;
     in nHoles;
    } Parcel;
```

From now on, you can make a Cartography with Parcel as below.

```
Parcel *Cartography;
```

This is what I'm thinking reasonable way...

Additionally, I'd like to let you know about my understanding of pointer * operation.
Pointer operator * is using for specify the name of pointer when it is declared.
And then * is using to point the value pointed by the pointer.

If you declared Cartography as a pointer to Parcel, the return value of malloc should be assigned to Cartography, the pointer, instead of *Cartography, the pointed value.

I think you are trying to handle several Parcels then you can use array of pointers or pointer to pointers to Parcel.

I hope this helps you to find a clue...

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare variables with `typedef`. Also, you shouldn't assign the pointer returned by `malloc()` to a non pointer type. `Cartography` is a pointer type, and dereferencing it with `*` means you are assigning a pointer to a type of `Parcel`. Here is the correct code:

```
typedef struct {
 Identification id;
 Ring edge;
 Ring *holes;
 in nHoles;
} Parcel;

Parcel *Cartography;
//this is the definition of Cartography



Cartography = malloc(sizeof(Parcel));

*(Cartography + idx) = readParcel(f);
```